# IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7f961e5d0d70>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"

Tags: xcode, command-line, build, archive

I inherited an application that I first build from the command line => npm run build.  Part of the process that is run as a result is the following functions.

```
function archive(options) {
  const proc = spawn('xcrun', [
    'xcodebuild',
    'archive',
    '-project',
    options.projectPath,
    '-scheme',
    options.scheme,
    '-archivePath',
    options.archivePath
  ], {
    stdio: 'inherit'
  });
  proc.on('close', (code) => {
    if (code !== 0) exit(code, 'Archive failed.');
    exportArchive(options);
  });
}

function exportArchive(options) {
  const proc = spawn('xcrun', [
    'xcodebuild',
    '-exportArchive',
    '-archivePath',
    options.archivePath,
    '-exportPath',
    options.exportPath,
    '-exportOptionsPlist',
    options.plistPath
  ], {
    stdio: 'inherit'
  });
  proc.on('close', (code) => {
    if (code !== 0) exit(code, 'Export archive failed.');
    rename(options);
  });
}
```

After this is completed, I open the Xcode project, select proper Team, and then perform Product\Archive. This then generates my .ipa.

This morning when performing the first step (npm run build) from the command line I got the following error:
 
** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **
2016-10-28 10:13:53.144 xcodebuild[4199:50183] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/1k/dwr2csfs5lnfrs7xq7520v_w0000gq/T/xxxxx xxxxx_2016-10-28_10-13-53.144.xcdistributionlogs'.
2016-10-28 10:13:53.590 xcodebuild[4199:50183] [MT] I**DEDistribution: Step failed: : Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error: exportArchive: The operation couldn’t be completed. (IDEDistributionErrorDomain error 1.)
Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
** EXPORT FAILED **
Export archive failed.**

Looking in Keychain Access I see that my "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority" certificate does not expire until 2023.
 
I do see a local distribution certificate that expired yesterday.
 
Am I getting this error because this expired distribution certificate is pointing to the "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority" certificate per this thread?
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/38472

I removed the expired distribution certificate in Keychain Access (I have another valid distribution certificate). I then tried to build again from the command line and still get the same error.

** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **
2016-10-28 11:31:14.735 xcodebuild[5202:74254] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/1k/dwr2csfs5lnfrs7xq7520v_w0000gq/T/xxxxx xxxxx_2016-10-28_11-31-14.734.xcdistributionlogs'.
2016-10-28 11:31:15.087 xcodebuild[5202:74254] [MT] ****IDEDistribution: Step failed: : Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
error: exportArchive: The operation couldn’t be completed. (IDEDistributionErrorDomain error 1.)
Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"
** EXPORT FAILED ******

Even with this error, I can still go into Xcode, select the proper Team, then proceed with the Product\Archive to complete the build of the application.

Comment: remove teamID from exportOptions.plist file or if you have teamID just use that in exportOptions.plist , you can get teamID from apple developer portal